# ! Undefined control sequence

Tags: math-mode, errors

I am continually receiving `! Undefined control sequence`.

```
3. $f(x) = -3x^{2} -5x +7$\\
$-3x^{2} - 5x +7$\\
$-3x^{2} - 5x = -7$\\
$x^{2} - 5/3x = -7/3$\\
$x^{2} - 5/3x +25/36 = -7/3 + 25/3$\\
$(x+ -5/6)^{2}=\fraq{\pm\sqrt{109}}{36}$\\
```

All is fine up until

```
\fraq{\pm\sqrt{109}}{36}$\\
```

I have placed this exact code in a seperate part of the document and it has run just fine, I am not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: It is `\frac` not `\fraq`.

Comment: Also, you should consider using the `align` environment from the `amsmath` package to typeset this portion of math. Using inline math (`$ ... $`) and newlines is not correct.

Comment: Also, your math is wrong. I assume you are missing `= 0` in the second line, and you are missing `-` before `x^{2}` in the fourth line. Also, the last line is plain wrong, since the left side squared does not mean ± on the right. The solution should be `x = \frac{1}{6}(\pm\sqrt{109} - 5)`.

Comment: Also, I'd say this question is off-topic as it is caused by a typo.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is a typo in the name of a command

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend that you (a) use inline fractions instead of `\frac` and (b) use an `align*` environment to organize the material.

Something like the following, then (note that I've modified some of your algebra):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' environment
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\setcounter{enumi}{2} % just for this example
\item Find the roots (``zeros'') of $f(x) = -3x^{2} -5x +7$.
\begin{align*}
-3x^{2} - 5x +7 &= 0\\
-3x^{2} - 5x &= -7\\
x^{2} + 5/3x &= 7/3\\
x^{2} + 5/3x +25/36 &= 7/3 + 25/36\\
(x+5/6)^{2}&=(7\cdot12+25)/36=109/36\\
x_{1,2}+5/6 &= \pm\sqrt{109}/6\\
x_{1,2} &= (-5\pm\sqrt{109}\,)/6
\end{align*}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```